# UWP Frame.GoBack with argument

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

The scenario is I have a calendar page, the page displays all days of the month with an Add button on each day:

As  I click the add button it takes me to a different page, if the user taps the hardware back button I want the app to go back to the calendar page but I want the page scrolled to the date the user originally tapped the add button for.

The scrolling to the date is fine - If, as a test, I navigate to a page with `NavigationEventArgs.Parameter = "2016-01-17"` then my page scrolls to the 17th.

The problem I have is that I don't seem to be able to specify a parameter on the `rootFrame.GoBack();` call.

So, is there a way to specify a parameter on the `rootFrame.GoBack();` call manually edit the backbuttonstack - if there is such a thing - so that the required argument is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way how to directly pass parameter using `GoBack` method but there is a workaround:

On your calendar page set `NavigationCacheMode` to `NavigationCacheMode.Required` so when you call `Frame.GoBack` the calendar page state will be the same as before you navigated to the different page:

```
<Page <!-- some unrelated XAML code -->
      NavigationCacheMode="Required"
      >
```

**EDIT** - reply to the comment:

What `NavigationCacheMode.Required` does is that the frame is not creating a new instance of the page every time you navigate to it but only for the first time. But the `OnNavigatedTo` method is still called every time you navigate to it. I don't know your code but if you're not doing so, you'll have to check whether there is any parameter passed and whether it's `string`. So in your `OnNavigatedTo` method override you'll do something like this:

```
string parameter = e.Parameter as string;

if (parameter != null)
{
    // Use parameter to scroll to date you need
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks, this does work but I have a `ScrollToDate` function that overrides it - I need this in for the normal navigation of the app (i.e. not via the back button) - is there a way to determine if you arrived at a page via the back button?

Comment: My code looks similar to what you have described - the only problem is the default would be no parameter = scroll to today's date, with a parameter = scroll to the date specified, if arriving via back button, don't scroll - just use the cached page. Not sure i'll be able to get that.

Comment: Now I understand! You may pass the parameter every time you navigate to the page. For example use `string.Empty` aka `""` for navigating to today's date and string with date to navigate to the date specified.